# UIActivityViewController not Working With Facebook Login

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, share

I am using **UIActivityViewController** in my new app for Facebook Share Option.

But if the user not login to the device, it dont working.. When select setting, Login page not appearing..

```
IActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

What can i do on this..?  Is that the Problem of my code or a Common Error..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6 introduced both the UIActivityViewController class and Social Framework, both of which may be used to integrate Twitter, Facebook and Sina Weibo functionality into iOS 6 applications. For general purpose requirements, the UIActivityViewController and SLComposeViewController classes provide an easy to implement path to social network integration.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
```

self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

In order to use the SLComposeViewController class, a number of steps should be performed in sequence. Firstly, the application may optionally check to verify whether a message can be sent to the specified social network service. This essentially equates to checking if a valid social network account has been configured on the device and is achieved using the isAvailableForServiceType: class method, passing through as an argument the type of service required from the following options:

1. SLServiceTypeFacebook
2. SLServiceTypeTwitter
3. SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo

Answer (score -1):

this is how you start ActivityIndicatorView with Loading lable

```
  UIActivityIndicatorView *tempSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];


 lable =[[UILabel alloc]init];
 lable.center = self.view.center;
 lable.text = @"Loading...";

 lable.hidden=NO;

 lable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 lable.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

 [lable sizeToFit];
 lable.center = CGPointMake(160, 255);

 tempSpinner.center = self.view.center;  


 [self.view addSubview:tempSpinner];

[self.view addSubview:lable];           
start where ever you want like this 
 [tempSpinner startAnimating]; 
stop it like this where ever you want
[tempSpinner stopAnimating]; 
hide unhide loading label as per requirement
```

Comment: `UIActivityViewController` is different than `UIActivityIndicatorView`